# How to use different backgrounds for ListView entries?

Tags: android, listview

I've got a ListView and I'm trying to use different backgrounds for the entries, how can I specify which entry should get which background?

What I'm doing is that I load the entries in the code, here:

```
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, listEntries));
```

So how can I specify a layout for every entry?

Kind Regards
Sam

Answer (score 1):

Write you own adapter that extends ArrayAdapter and override
 `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` 
method like this

```
View view;
String myString = getItem(position);
if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);            
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }
// here you can change background of view
return view;
```